# Rackspace Cloud Server and personal domains

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, rackspace

Can someone give me a no-nonsense, easy to understand explanation of the process for setting a domain I've registered at Namecheap to resolve to my Rackspace cloud server? This is not Rackspace Cloud Files or Cloud Sites. All tutorials seem to refer to those two products.

I set the A-Record to my cloud server IP, but this is apparently incorrect, as the URL in the address bar is replaced when the site loads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Log in to your namecheap account.
2. Go to My Account > Manage Domains
3. Select your domain
4. In the left pane, under "Host Management" select "All host records"
5. Remove the values for the pre-defined values (`@` and `www`)
6. Add your new record for `@` *
7. Submit the changes
8. Wait for TTL to expire, default is 1800 seconds(half an hour) (+ a few minutes of propagation)

*(`@` simply means the root of the zone, that is, the domain itself)

Was that no-nonsense enough?

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. All the other tutorials talking about using ns.rackspace.com must be the nonsense tutorials.